# Why does this ActiveRecord::save successfully save the model?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

```
$model-save()
```

Returns `true` and row is added to database. But I don't have field default values in database. What's wrong? THere is Action Controller and Scheme DB and Model ActiveRecord

Action Controller

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Requests();
    $model->user_id = null;

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {

        Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;

        $response = [
            'id'  => $model->id,
            'url' => 'request-lease/'.$model->url,
        ];

        return $response;

    } else {
        return BaseHtml::errorSummary($model, ['class' => 'alert alert-danger']);
    }
}
```

Model ACtiveRecord

```
class Requests extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
 {
/** Inactive status */
const STATUS_UNVERIFIED = 0;
/** Active status */
const STATUS_ACTIVE = 1;
/** Blocked status */
const STATUS_BLOCKED = 3;
/** Deleted status */
const STATUS_DELETED = 5;
/** Expired status */
const STATUS_EXPIRED = 6;

/**
 * Finance Array
 */
public static $trade_finance_arr = [
    1 => 'Leased',
    2 => 'Financed',
    3 => 'Owned',
    4 => 'Other'
];

/**
 * Trade condition array
 */
public static $trade_condition_arr = [
    1 => 'Excellent',
    2 => 'Good',
    3 => 'Fair',
    4 => 'Poor'
];


/**
 * @var string Model status.
 */
private $_status;

private $_credit_score;

public $offersCount;

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public static function tableName()
{
    return '{{%carbuilder_requests}}';
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'timestampBehavior' => [
            'class' => TimestampBehavior::className(),
        ],
    ];
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
//            [['user_id', 'vin', 'miles', 'zip', 'exterior_color', 'interior_color', 'comments', 'miles_per_year', 'started', 'term', 'credit_company', 'url', 'packages_ids', 'options_ids', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'total_msrp', 'styleId'], 'required'],
        [['user_id', 'zip', 'miles_per_year', 'started', 'term',
            'credit_company', 'status_id', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'total_msrp', 'styleId',
            'trade_finance','trade_bank','trade_term','trade_miles', 'trade_condition',
            'credit_score'], 'integer'],
        [['vin'], 'string', 'max' => 17],
        [['name', 'surname'], 'string', 'max' => 50],
        [['phone'], 'string', 'max' => 30],
        [['exterior_color', 'interior_color'], 'string', 'max' => 125],
        [['comments','trade_comments'], 'string', 'max' => 1000],
        [['url', 'pdf'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
        [['packages_ids', 'options_ids'], 'string', 'max' => 512],
        [['url'], 'unique'],
        [['income'], 'double']
        //[['user_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => User::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['user_id' => 'id']],
    ];
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'id' => 'ID',
        'user_id' => 'User ID',
        'vin' => 'Vin',
        'trade_miles' => 'Miles',
        'zip' => 'Zip',
        'exterior_color' => 'Exterior Color',
        'interior_color' => 'Interior Color',
        'comments' => 'Comments',
        'miles_per_year' => 'Miles Per Year',
        'started' => 'Started',
        'term' => 'Term',
        'credit_company' => 'Credit Company',
        'url' => 'Url',
        'status_id' => 'Status ID',
        'packages_ids' => 'Packages Ids',
        'options_ids' => 'Options Ids',
        'created_at' => 'Created At',
        'updated_at' => 'Updated At',
        'total_msrp' => 'Total Msrp',
        'styleId' => 'Style ID',
        'pdf' => 'PDF',
        'activation_at' => 'Activation At'
    ];
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function beforeSave($insert)
{
    if ($insert) {
        if ($this->user_id === null) {
            $this->user_id = (Yii::$app->user->id) ? Yii::$app->user->id : 0;
        }
    }

    return parent::beforeSave($insert);
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes)
{
    if ($insert) {
        $this->setUrl();
    }

    parent::afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes);
}

public static function findRequestbyUrl($node){


    return self::find()->where(['url'=>$node])->one();

}

/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getOffers()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Offers::className(), ['request_id' => 'id']);
}

/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getOffer()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Offers::className(), ['request_id' => 'id'])
        ->where(['user_id' => Yii::$app->user->id])
        ->inverseOf('request');
}

/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getUser()
{
    return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'user_id']);
}

/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getVehicle()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Vehicle::className(), ['styleId' => 'styleId']);
}

/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getBank()
{
    return $this->hasOne(CreditCompany::className(), ['id' => 'trade_bank']);
}

/**
 * @return integer
 */
public function getNewCountMessages()
{
    $count = 0;
    foreach($this->offers as $offer) {
        $count += $offer->newCountMessages;
    }
    return $count;
}

/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getPackages()
{
    if(empty($this->packages_ids)) return false;
    $packages = rtrim($this->packages_ids, ',');
    $packages = explode(',', $packages);
    return PackageOptions::find()->where(['optionsId' => $packages, 'styleId' => $this->styleId])->groupBy(['optionsId','styleId'])->all();
}

/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getOptions()
{
    if(empty($this->options_ids)) return false;
    $options = rtrim($this->options_ids, ',');
    $options = explode(',', $options);
    return PackageOptions::find()->where(['optionsId' => $options, 'styleId' => $this->styleId])->groupBy(['optionsId','styleId'])->all();
}
/**
 * Change or create Request url
 * @param string|null $url Url of request
 * @return boolean true if lease url was successfully changed
 */
public function setUrl($url = null)
{
    if($url) {
        Route::saveUrl($url, 'carbuilder/requests/summary');
        $this->url = $url;
        return $this->save(false);
    }

    $url = Inflector::slug($this->vehicle->make . '-' . $this->vehicle->model . '-' . $this->vehicle->trim .  '-' . $this->vehicle->year . '-' . $this->exterior_color . '-' . $this->id );

    Route::saveUrl($url, 'carbuilder/requests/summary');
    $this->url = $url;
    return $this->save(false);
}
}
```

Scheme database

```
CREATE TABLE `lfl_carbuilder_requests` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `vin` varchar(17) NOT NULL,
 `zip` int(5) NOT NULL,
 `exterior_color` varchar(125) NOT NULL,
  `interior_color` varchar(125) NOT NULL,
  `comments` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `miles_per_year` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `started` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `term` tinyint(2) NOT NULL,
  `credit_company` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `url` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `status_id` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `packages_ids` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
  `options_ids` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `total_msrp` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `styleId` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `pdf` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `trade_finance` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `trade_bank` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `trade_term` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `trade_miles` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `trade_condition` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `trade_comments` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `surname` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `state` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `location` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `credit_score` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `income` double NOT NULL,
  `activation_at` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `url` (`url`),
  KEY `status_id` (`status_id`),
  KEY `styleId` (`styleId`),
  KEY `FK_users_requests` (`user_id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=661 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Post request

```
exterior_color:"Deep Sea Blue Metallic"
interior_color:"Aluminum Hexagon W/Estoril Blue Matte Highlight"
options_ids:""
packages_ids:"200744520"
request_id:0
styleId:200744434
total_msrp:41550
user_id:0
```

Comment: please post you action, model and schema code

Comment: Maybe because `NULL` fields are allowed in your table? Maybe because somewhere in your code the properties of `$model` are automaticly set? We have not enough information to give you a good answer.

Comment: @Jerodev NULL are not allowed and also only few properties are set , but other fields

Comment: @VladimirKovalchuk can you post what data has been inserted in database just last two row

Comment: @shivaniparmar, (661, 0, '', 0, 'Deep Sea Blue Metallic', 'Aluminum Hexagon W/Estoril Blue Matte Highlight', '', 0, 0, 0, 0, 'bmw-2-series-228i-xdrive-sulev-2016-deep-sea-blue-metallic-661', 0, '200744520', '', 1463659610, 1463659610, 41550, '200744434', '', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '', NULL, NULL, NULL, '', '', NULL, 0, NULL);

Comment: @VladimirKovalchuk put at least last two row inserted in your question

Comment: (660, 0, '', 0, 'Melbourne Red Metallic', 'Aluminum Hexagon W/Black High-Gloss Highlight', '', 0, 0, 0, 0, 'bmw-4-series-435i-xdrive-2016-melbourne-red-metallic-660', 0, '', '', 1463657210, 1463657210, 50150, '200743646', '', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '', NULL, NULL, NULL, '', '', NULL, 0, NULL),
    (661, 0, '', 0, 'Deep Sea Blue Metallic', 'Aluminum Hexagon W/Estoril Blue Matte Highlight', '', 0, 0, 0, 0, 'bmw-2-series-228i-xdrive-sulev-2016-deep-sea-blue-metallic-661', 0, '200744520', '', 1463659610, 1463659610, 41550, '200744434', '', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '', NULL, NULL, NULL, '', '', NULL, 0, NULL);

Answer (score 0):

This Answer is consider that only you don't post id field other is filed.

In Your Database Id is Auto Increment

```
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
```

that's why it's increment by previous value and return id

Second,If You used in your form select box and the radio button it's take default value.

Comment: What about other fields? What the default values?

Comment: @VladimirKovalchuk if you have use a select box or a radio button in from than it's happen it's take default value of select box and radio button

Comment: only these properties are loaded in controller

`    exterior_color:"Deep Sea Blue Metallic"
    interior_color:"Aluminum Hexagon W/Estoril Blue Matte Highlight"
    options_ids:""
    packages_ids:"200744520"
    request_id:0
    styleId:200744434
    total_msrp:41550
    user_id:0`

Comment: Ok But Steel it's happen in Behavior able to set default value before the data saved called behavior @VladimirKovalchuk there is any behavior ?